# Rails:Is it possible to have 2 different each do loops on the same view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, each

Is it possible to have 2 .each do on the same view. With them doing different searches?

For example if I want to display all posts made by one specific user. I would have the following action in my users controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @posts = @user.posts
end
```

Then in the view I would have:

```
- @posts.each do |post|
   =post.title
```

Then If I wanted to display posts by other users on the same view. Using the above wont work as its only searching for the specific users posts.

Would I then create a new action?
Something like the following:

```
def showAll
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @posts = Post.where(:attribute => value).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Then back in the view page I would have another each.do with this one being the showAll action like:

```
- @posts.each do |post|
   =post.title
```

How would I achieve this? Is this the correct way to use actions?

Comment: `@posts = (@user == current_user) ? @user.posts : Post.where(:attribute => value).order("created_at DESC")` try this in your show action

Comment: There is probably some type of connection to which users you'll want to show data for.  Instead of finding individual users line by line I would first find the users by their common link (ex.  User.where(something: true).  Then loop through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in the same action itself

```
def show
  @posts = current_user.posts
  @other_posts = Post.where(:attribute => value).order("created_at DESC")
  # OR
  # @other_posts = Post.where.not(id: @posts).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

And then you can loop over them in view

```
%h2 Your posts
- @posts.each do |post|
   = post.title

%h2 Posts from other users
- @other_posts.each do |post|
   = post.title
```